# Add a Contact To Google SystemGroup

Tags: python, linux, contacts

I'm developing an app for adding a contact detail to google contacts using gdata and python. I can add a contact to "Other contacts" group but not to My Contact System Group.

here is the coding so far

```
def CreateMenu(self,nm,tp,em):

    new_contact = gdata.contacts.data.ContactEntry(name=gdata.data.Name(full_name=gdata.data.FullName(text=nm)))
    new_contact.phone_number.append(gdata.data.PhoneNumber(text=tp, primary='true', rel=gdata.data.WORK_REL))
    new_contact.email.append(gdata.data.Email(address=em, rel=gdata.data.WORK_REL))

    entry = self.gd_client.CreateContact(new_contact)
    if entry:
      print 'Creation successful!'
      print 'ID for the new contact:', entry.id.text
    else:
      print 'Upload error.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
feed = gd_client.GetGroups()
group = filter(lambda g: g.title.text == 'System Group: My Contacts', feed.entry)[0]
gmeminfo = gdata.contacts.data.GroupMembershipInfo(href=group.get_id())
new_contact.group_membership_info.append(gmeminfo)
```